# How can I make source location-independent within my application's directory tree?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I've got a tree like this:

```
repo
|-- dir
|   |-- main_script.sh
|   |-- subdir
|   |   |-- scritp1.sh
|   |   |-- script2.sh
```

I'd like to source script2.sh in script1.sh and source script1.sh in main_script.sh, then call main_script from repo:

```
$ pwd
.../repo
$ bash ./dir/main_script.sh
```

The problem is that with following scripts:

main_script.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ./subdir/script1.sh
```

script1.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source script2.sh
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Something useful"
```

I get error `./dir/main_script.sh: line 2: ./subdir/script1.sh: No such file or directory`. It seems that bash is looking for subdir not relative to main_script.sh but relative to working dir. I can change first script to get script's location using accepted answer form [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/refer-to-a-file-under-the-same-directory-of-a-script-found-in-path) or [this blog post](http://www.ostricher.com/2014/10/the-right-way-to-get-the-directory-of-a-bash-script/) making the  main_script.sh looking like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MYDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
source "${MYDIR}/subdir/script1.sh"
```

But then I get an error on sourcing the script2.sh in script1.sh:

`...repo/dir/subdir/script1.sh: line 2: script2.sh: No such file or directory`

as it seems that bash is looking for script2.sh in working directory.

I don't want to embed directory structure in every script.
So, the question is how to import relative scripts in bash properly?

Comment: BTW, as an aside, I'd suggest avoiding `.sh` extensions for bash scripts; this can be read to imply compatibility with `/bin/sh`. Something intended to be invoked as a command (`./yourscript`) generally shouldn't have an extension at all; something intended to be sourced as a library should have an extension that indicates which shell it's compatible with (ie. `yourlib.bash`, or `yourlib.sh` only if it's POSIX-compliant). History of the relevant irc.freenode.org #bash channel factoid is available @ http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH is honored by the `source` command. Thus, you can edit it in only one place, and the new PATH will be inherited by all others:

```
mydir=${BASH_SOURCE#/*}            # the normalization being done previously was needless
                                   # (and all-caps names are reserved for variables with
                                   # meaning to the shell or operating system).

PATH="$mydir:$mydir/subdir:$PATH"  # no export needed for a variable already in environment

source script1.sh                  # use non-qualified path
```