# Calling method declared in another bash file

Tags: bash

I have two bash files, in different folders. I want to call `abc()` method from bash file a from another bash file b. For that I can do an import. But what if this code is being used in production? I cannot simply provide my locally created files.

Example:

- main bash file that I am running "third"

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  .  /Users/r/r1-tests/r/fourth


  abc
  ```
- bash file called "fourth" which has method declared

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  function abc()
  {
      echo "hello"
  }
  ```

Can I do "without" using Import in "third"?

Comment: Hello, do you mean you want to call `abc()` from `third` without including `fourth`?

Comment: I mean this is going to be checked in Git. I can do in my local with Import. But how can I take care if this is a remote location?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot modify `third` file?

Comment: How do you _want_ it to work without the file with the code you want to execute being local? Give us a concrete idea of how you want it to find and load the code so we can tell you how to make it do that; right now, it's not clear what you want -- instead, you've only described what you _don't_ want.

Comment: Yes,I mean I cannot simply add the path of my locally created file "fourth" in "third". This is perhaps an issue I will encounter if my code is pushed to Git, where the code is expecting a file that has been taken from Git location and not from my local file. Do I make sense? In other words, how can I modify this file if I check in my code in Git?

Comment: Are _both_ files checked into the same git repo, so you want to search for one file in a path relative to the other one? Or do you want your script to go out over the network to the git repository to find the other file? Or is it something else you're asking for?

Comment: If it's just about searching relative to your current source file, that's a duplicate of existing questions already in the knowledge base.

Comment: The first part is right. Both files are checked in git repo. So, If that is the case, I cannot simply mention my local path on one file, right? This code will be used by other developers.

Comment: Please guide me to the right link.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-can-i-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itsel/57666344#57666344

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902054/how-can-i-make-source-location-independent-within-my-applications-directory-tre

Answer (score 0):

> But what if this code is being used in production?

Then include it too.

Your problems seems no to be including files, but including files not using absolute paths. So include it using a **relative** path. Relative to.. for example the current file:

```
. "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"/dir/with/fourth
```

- [Get last dirname/filename in a file path argument in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294072/get-last-dirname-filename-in-a-file-path-argument-in-bash)
- [How can I get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-can-i-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itsel)

Or relative to the git repository:

```
. "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/some/dir/dir/with/fourth
```

- [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)